# How to foreach and group like this on blade laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm retrieving tracking data from the DHL API, as follows the data I get :
[Data API From DHL TRACKING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AbA4.png)

I use foreach in laravel blade, the result is like this:
[Foreach on Blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUnh8.png)

How to make a foreach group where date in laravel blade like this :
[View on Website DHL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8gVp.png)

Please Help all, thank you..

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the result from API by date using Laravel's collection.

```
@php
    $groupedResult = collect([$apiResult])->groupBy(function($item) {
                      return Carbon::parse($item['timestamp'])->format('Y-m-d');
                  });
@endphp

@foreach($groupedResult as $date => $row)
 {{ $date }}
 @foreach($row as $item)
   // each day's transactions
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But I will suggest to process the data in controller, and then send to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Me personally I'd do that all in the controller. Hit the api with only the info you need (looks like there is more there than you actually need), process that data in the controller and build your own collection and do sorting and grouping from that data and then send to the front.
Keep your logic in the controllers.

Comment: Yes Sir, i made that logic in controllers, and sent on blade
Thanks 